# Appending Row Data to Select Statement in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am getting the values at specified columns at random rows within a table such that:

```
SELECT <COLUMN_NAME> 
  FROM ( SELECT <COLUMN_NAME> 
           FROM <SCHEMA>.<TABLE_NAME>
          ORDER BY dbms_random.value ) 
 WHERE rownum < <RANDOM_NUMBER>
```

And that works as it should. Now I want to append the data for the entire row to the result rows. For example if my table is:

```
Column A            Column B             Column C         Column D
data1                data2                data3            data4
data5                data6                data7            data8
```

If my specified column is column B, my query returns:

```
data2

data6
```

I want it to return:

```
data2, data1, data2, data3, data4
data6, data5, data6, data7, data8
```

I'm assuming its something like SELECT < COLUMN_NAME >, *     ........?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, if < COLUMN_NAME > is unique in the table:

```
SELECT r.<COLUMN_NAME>, t_append.* FROM (
SELECT <COLUMN_NAME> FROM <TABLE_NAME> t_random ORDER BY dbms_random.random ) r
inner join <TABLE_NAME> t_append on t_append.<COLUMN_NAME> = r.<COLUMN_NAME>
WHERE rownum <= dbms_random.value(1,<MAX_RANDOM_NUMBER_YOU_WANT>)
```

### Update based on additional requirements (multiple columns)

```
SELECT r.<COLUMN_NAME_1>, r.<COLUMN_NAME_2>, etc, t_append.* 
FROM (
    SELECT <COLUMN_NAME_1>, r.<COLUMN_NAME_2>, etc..
    FROM <TABLE_NAME> t_random ORDER BY dbms_random.random ) r
    inner join <TABLE_NAME> t_append on 
        t_append.<COLUMN_NAME_1> = r.<COLUMN_NAME_1> 
    AND t_append.<COLUMN_NAME_2> = r.<COLUMN_NAME_2> 
    AND etc...
    WHERE rownum <= dbms_random.value(1,<MAX_RANDOM_NUMBER_YOU_WANT>)
```

Again... it only works if the set of columns you use uniquely identifies a record in your table.

Comment: I should have added: I would like to be able to specify multiple columns as well. So if I specified column B and C, in the result I would get B's value and C's value followed by the entire row. How would I restructure the SQL to accept that?

Comment: You rock Matthew, thanks a lot. And I know the columns need to be unique. I'm actually using this statement with my composite keys.

Comment: Hey, how would I correctly modify this statement if instead of finding random rows. I had specific values in column 1 and column 2 which I wanted to find the row for?

Comment: In the inner select, replace "WHERE rownum<= ..." with "WHERE <column_name> = <value you want in column> AND <other_column_name> = <value you want in other column>"

Comment: could you explain how the random selection is done within your provided SQL statement. When I tried to use it, it worked for lower numbers (<30), but as they increased (>100) they become less random. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really.  How are you measuring "randomness"?  Maybe you should post a second question with all the relevant details.  Non-helpful link: [random number generator](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/121411_1611_SecureRando1.png)

Comment: I'm using your sql statement except for the last line, I do "WHERE rownum <= <X>" instead. I do this because I want "X" number of random rows. You see, its not the amount of rows I want to be random, its the rows themselves that I need to be random.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Well, I guess I just want to know if its doing what I think its doing. Would "WHERE rownum <= <X>" give me "X" number of random columns from the database. It seems like it, but like I said, the higher number I put into X, the less random the results seem.

Comment: It would give you X number of random _rows_ from the database, not columns.  But, in any case, it will not return more than the number of rows in the table.  So, if you have 200 rows in your table and specified X = 500, you'll get 200 every time (but the order of them will still be random).

Comment: Okay cool, last issue I'm having is that certain tables are returning one less row than my specified <X> number. If I set x to 5, then I get 4 row results, and I have confirmed that there are more than 5 rows in table. Any clue why that may be happening off the top of your head?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87521/discussion-between-matthew-mcpeak-and-user2665166).

Comment: earlier you said I could find a specific row given column values using "WHERE <column_name> = <value you want in column> AND <other_column_name> = <value you want in other column>". How would I modify this to get multiple rows using multiple column value pairs? (Basically so I don't have to keep recalling this statement for each column pair)

Comment: Use `(columnA, columnB) IN ( ('1st col A value','1st col B value'), ('2nd col A value','2nd col B value'), ... etc)`